# How to reshape the speech data as LSTM input?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, speech

I'm classifying voice and non-voice in a speech data with 3630371 data points and 39 features each. i.e shape of speech data is (3630371, 39). How do I reshape it as LSTM input. What must be the 3D input_shape or what are the values for "Samples", "Timestep" and "Features".

Is the following correct?

```
data.reshape(3630371, 1, 39)
LSTM(32, input_shape = (1, 39))
```

Please Help! I have no clue.

Comment: What are your 39 features? Or do you have 3 million audio clips that each consist of a sequence of 39 samples?

Comment: It's all clips merged into single one which has 3 million chunks and each chunk of 20ms has 39 features.

Comment: Ok so if you have 1 sequence of 3 million timestamps that each have 39 features then shape should be (1, 3630371, 39). Not much you can do with only one training sample though and an LSTM isn't going to work with a sequence that long. How is the data labeled? Do you have a voice/non-voice label for each chunk or just one for the whole series?

Comment: It is labeled for each chunk. How do I feed it to LSTM?

Comment: If you have a label for each chunk then your no classifying sequences, your classifying each individual chunks so you can just use a Dense layer. Unless you want to do something like put N chunks together and classify whether at least one of them contains a voice

Answer (score 0):

LSTM input: `(no of samples, timesteps, features)`

```
data.reshape(3630371, 1, 39)
LSTM(32, input_shape = (1, 39))
```

In the above code, you are essentially having only 1 timestep which doesn't utilize the abilities of LSTM. What you are doing is: LSTM in the first timestep takes a 39-dimensional vector as input and iteration terminate.

Another option is to give a scalar for 39 timesteps.

```
data.reshape(3630371, 39, 1)
```

Here the LSTM loops 39 times (39 timesteps) but taking a scalar as input at every timestep.

In fact any other combination will do until the `no_timestep x feature_dim = total_input_dimension`. Generally, it depends a lot on the domain you are working which fixes these numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't the last parameter be no. of features which is 39?

Comment: If your sample is described by a 39-dimensional vector, (i.e) if you want to classify each and every 39 dim vectors into voice and non-voice, the above approach will valid. (here the number of data points you have is 3630371).
If you want to have an overall description for 3630371 39 dimensional vectors, which means you have only one sample (datapoint) and the number of timesteps becomes 3630371, feature dim is 39. LSTM won't work in this case.